# Can I combine a canvas and an image element in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert my "image" variable to a canvas type and combine it with "canvas" variable(boxes) element to create another canvas element. This output canvas would have the image behind and the canvas with boxes on the front.
I am referring to http://jsfiddle.net/bnwpS/878/

HTML:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
const container = document.getElementById("output");
const image = await faceapi.bufferToImage(imageUpload.files[0]);
const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(image);
container.append(image);
container.append(canvas);
```

I have tried one thing but was unsuccessful:

1. created another canvas element using createElement('canvas') and then using drawImage() to draw the image and the canvas on it, however the result comes out as black.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve and what isn't working other than the black image. Certainly that is fixable, but you haven't provided the code you used.

Comment: @seesharper I have edited my question. let me know if it still unclear. I can include the whole code but then it would be 50 lines of code. Should I include a github gist of the code? [link to code](https://github.com/vinamramunot-tech/Deep-Learning-Yolo/blob/e31f1e13da714f338150921a6ccfcb605ef2d80a/src/static/js/render_face_api.js#L32)

Comment: So you want to write an image to the canvas and then draw boxes on top of that?

Comment: @seesharper yes currently what the code does it first it appends the uploaded image to the div "container" and the appends the canvas "boxes" on that same div "container". However, I want to combine both the uploaded image and canvas boxes together in another canvas element and output the final canvas.

Comment: Is it just that you want one to visually overlay the other, or do you need to combine them into the one canvas?

Comment: @seesharper I want to combine them both as one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223387/discussion-between-vinny-and-see-sharper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing the image to the canvas using this function:

```
function writeImageToCanvas(image, cvs) {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    img.onload = () => {
      cvs.width = img.width;
      cvs.height = img.height;
      const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      resolve();
    };
    img.src = image.src;
  });
}
```

Note this is an async function, so will need to use `writeImageToCanvas(img,cvs).then(...` or else use await and mark the calling function as async.

Comment: I have tried this solution however it did not work. I am trying to combine two overlaying images. https://pinetools.com/overlay-images. I want to achieve something like this as mentioned in the above link. I have looked into opencv.js however they do not have anything. Please let me know if you have some resource or api that would do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? This will certainly work for writing an image to a canvas. You can write a second image on top using the same code but not setting the width and height. However I'm not sure of your exact use case - do you need transparency, and why can't you overlay using position: absolute with two images for example?

Comment: BTW the very link you provide is to a set of free js tools for image overlay, so what's wrong with their API?

Comment: The pinetools overlay that I mentioned does not have an api. It was miscommunication on my end. I did not state the correct use case. I wanted to overlay two images and download them. The download functionality is not working for me because I am targeting to download the two images together. The pine tools is the functionality that I need but they do not have an api for it.

Comment: @Vinny, if you inspect the pinetools merge image page, you'll see the the javascript right there, and that they are using methods very similar to what I proposed above. If you have two images, the idea would be to take the larger one and write it to a canvas as above, then take the smaller one and write it to the *same* canvas at whatever coordinates you want (as above but without the sizing step and using your coordinates at the drawImage step). Then you can download the merged image.

Answer (score 0):

```
img1.onload = () => {
  canvas.width = img1.width;
  canvas.height = img1.height;
  img2.src = 'img2.png';
};

img2.onload = () => {
  context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
  context.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);

  const imgUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  this.selectedImg = imgUrl;
  // convert canvas to file format
  canvas.toBlob((blob: any) => {
    let file = new File([blob], image.name, { type: 'image/jpeg' });
    console.log(file);
  }, 'image/jpeg');
};
img1.src = 'img1.png';
```

Taken from https://youtu.be/th8l_l_WA3k